# Creating a winner checker for a Tic-Tac-Toe GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, tic-tac-toe

I am creating a Tic-Tac-Toe GUI for a school project. I am confused on how to make something that checks wins would like some help or tips on how to create a winner checker. I am also confused as to why my console is spammed with Event errors whenever I click a button. All help appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    int count = 0;
    int letter = 0;
    int round = 2;
    JPanel j;
    JButton[] button;
    String[] letters;

    public Main() { // The GUI
        setTitle("Tic-Tac-Toe");
        setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        setLocation(400, 200);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        j = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        this.add(j);
        button = new JButton[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { //9 Buttons
            button[i] = new JButton();
            j.add(button[i]);
            button[i].setEnabled(true);
            button[i].addActionListener(this);
        }
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main world = new Main();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        count++;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
            if (button[i] == e.getSource()) { //sets buttons to X or O
                if (letter == 0) {
                    button[i].setText("X");
                    button[i].setEnabled(false);
                    letter++;
                    letters[i] = "X"; //would like to use to check wins
                } else {
                    button[i].setText("O");
                    button[i].setEnabled(false);
                    letter = 0;
                    letters[i] = "O"; //would like to use to check wins
                }

            }
            if (count >= 9) {//Resets board and starts a new round
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Its a Draw! Start round "+ round +"!");
                round++;
                count = 0;
                button[i].setText("");
                button[i].setEnabled(true);

                button[i + 1].setText("");
                button[i + 1].setEnabled(true);

                button[i + 2].setText("");
                button[i + 2].setEnabled(true);

                button[i + 3].setText("");
                button[i + 3].setEnabled(true);

                button[i + 4].setText("");
                button[i + 4].setEnabled(true);

                button[i + 5].setText("");
                button[i + 5].setEnabled(true);

                button[i + 6].setText("");
                button[i + 6].setEnabled(true);

                button[i + 7].setText("");
                button[i + 7].setEnabled(true);

                button[i + 8].setText("");
                button[i + 8].setEnabled(true);

                button[i + 9].setText("");
                button[i + 9].setEnabled(true);
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And every time I click a button, errors pop out similar to this:

```
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: could you add the error log too  ?

Comment: Yup - added it to the post

Answer (score 2):

You get null pointer exception because you didn't allocate spaces for your array. Try:

```
String[] letters = new String[9];
```

When you run with this revision, you will see Array index out of bounds: 9, because your for-loop should only iterate up to 8, having started from 0.

In order to check if someone has won, first find out which square corresponds to which array position. Then, you can see if one of the symbols has taken one of the eight possible winning positions in the array. For example, X taking a diagonal line wins. This can be done with:

```
if (possibility1 || possibility2 || possibility3... || possibility8)
    [code to run on winning result]
```

This check occurs every time a player enters his X or O into the board. In your case, it the place where you wrote "//would like to use to check wins".

Also, I'm not sure if you know this already, but there's only one error in that console output, not many. It shows a sequence of calls leading up the error (top) with the bottommost calling another, which calls another, upwards.